# String incrementation

Tags: python

I've just started to learn Python and I'm doing some exercises in codewars. The instructions are simple: If the string already ends with a number, the number should be incremented by 1.
If the string does not end with a number. the number 1 should be appended to the new string.

I wrote this:

```
    if strng[-1].isdigit():
        return strng.replace(strng[-1],str(int(strng[-1])+1))
    else:
        return strng + "1"
    return(strng)
```

It works sometimes (for example 'foobar001 - foobar002', 'foobar' - 'foobar1'). But in other cases it adds 1 to each number at the end (for example 'foobar11' - 'foobar22'), I would like to achieve a code where the effect is to add only +1 to the ending number, for example when 'foobar99' then 'foobar100', so the number has to be considered as a whole. I would be grateful for advices for beginner :)!

Answer (score 2):

## First, you have to make some assumptions

Assuming that the numerical values are always at the end of string and the first character from the right that is not numeric would mark the end of the non-number string, i.e.

```
>>> input = "foobar123456"
>>> output = 123456 + 1
```

## Second, we need to assume that number exists at the end of the string.

So if we encounter a string without a number, we need to decide if the python code should throw an error and not try to add 1.

```
>>> input = "foobar"
```

Or we decide that we automatically generate a `0` digit, which would require us to do something like

```
input = input if input[-1].isdigit() else input + "0"
```

Lets assume the latter decision for simplicity of the explanation.

## Next we will try to read the numbers from the right until you get to a non-digit

Lets use `reversed()` to flip the string and then a `for`-loop to read the characters until we reach a non-number, i.e.

```
>>> s = "foobar123456"
>>> output = 123456

>>> for character in reversed(s):
...     if not character.isdigit(): 
...         break
...     else:
...         print(character)
... 
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

## Now, lets use a list to keep the digits characters

```
>>> digits_in_reverse = []
>>> for character in reversed(s):
...     if not character.isdigit(): 
...         break
...     else:
...         digits_in_reverse.append(character)
... 
>>> digits_in_reverse
['6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1']
```

Then we reverse it:

```
>>> ''.join(reversed(digits_in_reverse))
'123456'
```

And convert it into an integer:

```
>>> int(''.join(reversed(digits_in_reverse)))
123456
```

Now the +1 increment would be easy!

## How do we find the string preceding the number?

```
# The input string.
s = "foobar123456"
s = s if s[-1].isdigit() else s + "0"

# Keep a list of the digits in reverse.
digits_in_reverse = []

# Iterate through each character from the right.
for character in reversed(s):
    # If we meet a character that is not a digit, stop.
    if not character.isdigit(): 
        break
    # Otherwise, keep collecting the digits.
    else:
        digits_in_reverse.append(character)

# Reverse, the reversed digits, then convert it into an integer.        
number_str = "".join(reversed(digits_in_reverse))
number = int(number_str)

print(number)

# end of string preceeding number.
end = s.rindex(number_str)
print(s[:end])

# Increment +1
print(s[:end] + str(number + 1))
```

[output]:

```
123456
foobar
foobar123457
```

## Bonus: Can you do it with a one-liner?

Not exactly one line, but close:

```
import itertools

s = "foobar123456"
s = s if s[-1].isdigit() else s + "0"

number_str = "".join(itertools.takewhile(lambda ch: ch.isdigit(), reversed(s)))[::-1]

end = s.rindex(number_str)

print(s[:end] + str(int(number_str) + 1))
```

## Bonus: But how about regex?

Yeah, with regex it's pretty magical, you would still make the same assumption as how we started, and to **make your regex as simple as possible** you have to **add another assumption** that the alphabetic characters preceding the number can only be made up of a-z or A-Z.

Then you can do this:

```
import re

s = "foobar123456"
s = s if s[-1].isdigit() else s + "0"

alpha, numeric = re.match("([a-zA-z]+)(\d.+)", s).groups()
print(alpha + str(int(numeric) + 1))
```

But you have to understand the regex which might be a steep learning, see https://regex101.com/r/9iiaCW/1

Comment: Neither the *itertools* nor *re* approach solve the prerequisite that if the input is, for example 'a' that the output should be 'a1'

Comment: Added an additional assumption and pre-function "digit appending"

Comment: I believe I have the regex solution worked out for almost any case~ @Stuart

Comment: Like all l33tcoding, `A QA engineer walks into a bar, and orders a beer.` =)

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution would be:

Have two empty variables `head` (=non-numeric prefix) and `tail` (numeric suffix). Iterate the string normally, from left to right. If the current character is a digit, add it to `tail`. Otherwise, join `head` and `tail`, add the current char to `head` and empty `tail`. Once complete, increment `tail` and return `head` + `tail`:

```
def foo(s):
    head = tail = ''

    for char in s:
        if char.isdigit():
            tail += char
        else:
            head += tail + char
            tail = ''

    tail = int(tail or '0')
    return head + str(tail + 1)
```

Leading zeroes (`x001` -> `x002`), if needed, left as an exercise ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your string, you need to check if it is alpha numeric or not. if it is alpha numeric, then you need to check the last character, whether it is digit or not.

now if above condition satisfy then you need to get the index of first digit in the string which make a integer number in last of string.

once you got the index then, seperate the character and numeric part.
once done, convert numerical string part to interger and add 1. after this join both character and numeric part. that is your answer.

```
# your code goes here

string = 'randomstring2345'
index = len(string) - 1
if string.isalnum() and string[-1].isdigit():
    
    while True:
        if string[index].isdigit():
            index-=1
        else:
            index+=1
            break
        if index<0:
            break

char_part = string[:index]
int_part = string[index:]
integer = 0
if int_part:
    integer = int(''.join(int_part)) 

modified_int = integer + 1

new_string = ''.join([char_part, str(modified_int)])
print(new_string)
```

output

`randomstring2346`

Comment: This raises *ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'g2345'*

Comment: @Stuart thanks, i forgot to add a little modified part

Answer (score 0):

Regex can be a useful tool in python~ Here I make two groups, the first `(.*?)` is as few of anything as possible, while the second `(\d*$)` is as many digits at the end of the string as possible. For more in depth explanation see [regexr](https://regexr.com/6p106).

```
import re

def increment(s):
    word, digits = re.match('(.*?)(\d*$)', s).groups() 
    digits = str(int(digits) + 1).zfill(len(digits)) if digits else '1'
    return word + digits

print(increment('foobar001'))
print(increment('foobar009'))
print(increment('foobar19'))
print(increment('foobar20'))
print(increment('foobar99'))
print(increment('foobar'))
print(increment('1a2c1'))
print(increment(''))
print(increment('01'))
```

Output:

```
foobar002
foobar010
foobar20
foobar21
foobar100
foobar1
1a2c2
1
02
```

Comment: If I understand the OP's requirements correctly, then if the input to this function is, for example, '1a2c' then the output should be '1a2c1' but the actual output is '2'

Comment: @Stuart updated to account for such a strange case~

Answer (score -1):

**Source**

```
def solve(data):
    result = None
    if len(data) == 0 or not data[-1].isdigit():
        result = data + str(1) #appending 1
    else:
        lin = 0
        for index, ch in enumerate(data[::-1]):
            if ch.isdigit():
                lin = len(data) - index -1
            else:
                break
        result = data[0 : lin] + str(int(data[lin:]) + 1) # incrementing result
    return result
    pass

print(solve("Hey123"))
print(solve("aaabbbzzz"))
```

**output :**

```
Hey124
aaabbbzzz1
```